# How to pass the private key as a String in Java in order to connect via SFTP using SSHJ?

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, private-key

The following code works to connect via SFTP, the **directory path** of the key is used in order to load it.

Here's the current code (*I've specified the libraries just in case*)

```
import net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient;
import net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.keyprovider.KeyProvider;
import net.schmizz.sshj.transport.verification.PromiscuousVerifier;

SSHClient sftp = new SSHClient();
KeyProvider privateKey = sftp.loadKeys("/home/sample/.ssh/id_rsa");
sftp.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());
sftp.connect("111.222.333.444");
sftp.authPublickey("sample", privateKey);
```

---

##### Is there a way to pass the Private Key's content as a String instead of using its directory path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can invoke the follwoing method of the library to support the use-case.

```
/**
 * Creates a {@link KeyProvider} instance from passed strings. Currently only PKCS8 format private key files are
 * supported (OpenSSH uses this format).
 * <p/>
 *
 * @param privateKey     the private key as a string
 * @param publicKey      the public key as a string if it's not included with the private key
 * @param passwordFinder the {@link PasswordFinder} that can supply the passphrase for decryption (may be {@code
 *                       null} in case keyfile is not encrypted)
 *
 * @return the key provider ready for use in authentication
 *
 * @throws SSHException if there was no suitable key provider available for the file format; typically because
 *                      BouncyCastle is not in the classpath
 * @throws IOException  if the key file format is not known, etc.
 */   
public KeyProvider loadKeys(String privateKey, String publicKey, PasswordFinder passwordFinder) throws IOException
```

If that is not available in the version of library you're using then considered upgrading it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.schmizz</groupId>
    <artifactId>sshj</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Oh man, I was so confused as to why that method also required the public key, so I just provided an empty string and still worked, thanks!